# Can connect to router, but not Internet

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, home-networking

Sorry about this probably very n00b question. However, I've little idea where to start.

My router is at 192.168.1.254. I can ping it and log in.

My laptop (Ubuntu 14.04) has been given an address by DHCP. Great.

```
$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (74.125.24.147) 56(84) bytes of data.
... Destination host unreachable.
```

So DNS seems to be working (hence the IP address above, CCIIW), but no connection to the outside world.

I have a few devices connected to that router. They all can connect to the Internet. They include Ubuntu 14.04 laptops (another one), Mac OS X, iPhone, Android, etc.

The laptop can connect to the Internet just fine at work; it's only when I bring it home that it can't connect.

I'm happy to post additional output, but I don't want to start off with a 400 line TL;DR.

UPDATE:
Problem is still latent including through a reboot. Network interfaces are 
apparently configured with dhcp, however when I do `sudo dhclient`,

```
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

and there's just a network unreachable error.

Upon connecting and disconnecting the wireless interface through the gui, (clicking on the applet) suddenly we get the output from route -n shown below. I've ack-grepped the entirety of /etc for 192.168.192.9 to no avail.

Clearly something is setting up the route badly. But I can't find out what, and why didn't dhclient *just* work?

Output of `ifconfig -a`:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:323652 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:323652 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:99228239 (99.2 MB)  TX bytes:99228239 (99.2 MB)

lxcbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <scrubbed>  
      inet addr:10.0.3.1  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::3c4e:76ff:fe8d:952b/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:8596 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:9237 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:4833338 (4.8 MB)  TX bytes:1745576 (1.7 MB)

veth76QSB1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <scrubbed>
      inet6 addr: fe80::fc1a:ddff:fec9:f778/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:8596 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:9096 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:4953682 (4.9 MB)  TX bytes:1710443 (1.7 MB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <scrubbed>
      inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <scrubbed>
      inet addr:192.168.1.99  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::7e7a:91ff:fe7b:ce51/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:244352 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:27359 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:25261686 (25.2 MB)  TX bytes:3141682 (3.1 MB)


 route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use  Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.192.9   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
192.168.192.9   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 wlan0
```

I only have traceroute6.That gave:

```
 traceroute6 208.67.220.220
traceroute: unknown host 208.67.220.220
```

Comment: post the output of ifconfig

Comment: We also need the outputs of `route -n` and `traceroute 208.67.220.220`

Comment: This really sounds like a route misconfiguration. You can resolve dns and talk to a DHCP server because those are located in the same subnet that your Ubuntu laptop is directly connected on and directly connected routes take precedence over others. Without what @geewee asked, it will be impossible to troubleshoot much further.

Comment: @geewee I have added the information now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

> 0.0.0.0         192.168.192.9   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0

shows that the default gateway is set to 192.168.192.9, where it should be 192.168.1.254. Please check whether it is configured manually, and remove the configuration so that the router can set itself as default gateway through DHCP.

Comment: Thanks for this. If it is configured manually, how would I know and how would I then change that?

Comment: I am not that familiar with NIC-configuration in Linux, it should be configured through ifconfig command.

Comment: I've added an alias for `home_router` which removes the default gateway and adds in mine. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a proxy issue. Your laptop still uses earlier proxy settings. Go to
System settings -> Network -> System proxy
Change setting to your home network and try to connect.